# Http Junit service call

Tags: rest, junit4

Is it possible to make two http service call in one junit test method.

i have a scenario , like one http call will return me the tenants and other will return me the adapter configuration and i want to check weather the adapter configuration returned to me is configured to the above tenant or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Also we have http unit like junit